# R: Create a new data frame from an old one by checking if the old data frame's first column value matches a third data frame's first column value

Tags: r

For example, let's say I have a first data frame that looks like this:

```
1   -0.123  -0.306  inf 1.043   0.000   0.010   0.000   0.653   0.000   0.091   0.000   0.009   0.000   3.097   0.000   0.137   0.002
2   -0.142  -0.170  inf 1.035   0.000   0.064   0.000   0.538   0.000   0.560   0.000   0.289   0.000   3.168   0.000   6.182   0.000
3   -0.160  -0.143  inf 1.027   0.000   0.086   0.000   0.401   0.000   0.631   0.000   0.400   0.000   3.348   0.000   0.130   0.000
4   -0.176  -0.117  inf 1.020   0.000   0.107   0.000   0.249   0.000   0.592   0.000   0.435   0.000   3.526   0.000   0.402   0.001
5   -0.191  -0.110  inf 1.014   0.000   0.133   0.000   0.091   0.000   0.514   0.000   0.425   0.000   3.644   0.001   0.598   0.001
6   -0.206  -0.099  inf 1.008   0.000   0.162   0.000   6.247   0.000   0.435   0.001   0.392   0.001   3.675   0.001   0.707   0.002
7   -0.220  -0.093  0.976   1.003   0.000   0.194   0.000   6.168   0.001   0.377   0.001   0.352   0.001   3.602   0.003   0.740   0.003
8   -0.233  -0.092  inf 0.999   0.000   0.226   0.000   6.137   0.001   0.353   0.001   0.302   0.001   3.445   0.004   0.712   0.005
9   -0.246  -0.124  inf 0.996   0.000   0.258   0.000   6.145   0.001   0.363   0.001   0.252   0.001   3.242   0.004   0.620   0.006
10  -0.259  -0.119  inf 0.994   0.000   0.289   0.000   6.172   0.001   0.393   0.001   0.206   0.001   3.028   0.005   0.456   0.008
```

I want to create a new second data frame from this first data frame - on one condition. I have a third frame that looks like this:

```
1   0.00038 0.75053 0.50    35  6000    0.75346
7   0.00038 0.75053 0.50    35  6300    0.60313
10  0.00038 0.75053 0.50    35  6450    0.55122
```

and I want to use only the rows where the first column value exists.
Ultimately, I want the second data frame to look like this:

```
1   -0.123  -0.306  inf 1.043   0.000   0.010   0.000   0.653   0.000   0.091   0.000   0.009   0.000   3.097   0.000   0.137   0.002
7   -0.220  -0.093  0.976   1.003   0.000   0.194   0.000   6.168   0.001   0.377   0.001   0.352   0.001   3.602   0.003   0.740   0.003
10  -0.259  -0.119  inf 0.994   0.000   0.289   0.000   6.172   0.001   0.393   0.001   0.206   0.001   3.028   0.005   0.456   0.008
```

Comment: There are no values in the first data.frame's first column that match values in the third data.frame's first column.

Comment: @Sirius `1`, `7`, `10` match between the two in this example.

Comment: oh I thought those were just rownumbers.

Answer (score 1):

can be done like this:

```
df1[ df1[,1] %in% df3[,1], ]
```

Comment: Is `df1` data frame 1 and `df` data frame 3?

Comment: yes! updated, that was the intention all along

Comment: What does `df3[,3]` mean? I thought it would be `df3[,1]' for column 1, no?

Comment: cranky, getting everything possible wrong with this. should be column 1 through out, df1 = first data.frame, df3 = third data.frame. apologies! (updated!). hopefully you still realize how straight forward this is.